# extending Adminhtml Product edit page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, adminhtml, overrides, magento-2.1

In Previous `Magento released versions (2.0.*)` I have successfully extended and it's working fine. When comes to `Magento 2.1.0` the same functionality not working. I have tried below code. If I went to wrong through me right direction.

Here I have directly wrote core file (later I will convert to local).

**My Code**

**root/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit.phtml**

```
 ...
     <div style="width: 100%;height: 20px;">
            Welcome to Magento 2
        </div>
    ...
    core files code
    ..
```

**Previous versions my code is**

**Training/Learning/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit"
                type="Training\Learning\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit" />
</config>
```

**Training/Learning/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit.php**

```
<?php

namespace Training\Learning\Block\Adminhtml\Product;

class Edit extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit
{
    protected $_template = 'Training_Learning::catalog/product/edit.phtml';
}
```

**Training/Learning/view/adminhtml/template/catalog/product/Edit.php**

```
...
         <div style="width: 100%;height: 20px;">
                Welcome to Magento 2
            </div>
        ...
        core files code
        ..
```

It's working fine in Magento 2.0.* versions.

Any help on this?

Comment: Magento 2.1 move traditional form to ui_component form. What you exactly need that why you overwrite whole form class?

Comment: @SohelRana, I Want to send Product information to Other API. for that I want to put button on product edit page.

Comment: only you need to add header button like save, reset etc?

Comment: @SohelRana, No, I want to insert before `Enable Product` field.

Comment: @SohelRana, any help on this?

Comment: Need some investigation, I will be back if find something positive for you

Comment: Here's a doc about customizing the product form in 2.1 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html Let us know if there's something missing/not clear